# How to encrypt a disk with 2 Windows OSes and 3 partitions with Vera Crypt?

Tags: encryption, windows, veracrypt, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a disk with an MBR partition scheme and 3 partitions. On the first partition, there's a Windows 7 C: drive which I keep to play some retro games that won't run on newer Windows. The second partition is a Windows 7 D: partition. It's a relic from times when separate data partition was a good practice. The third partition contains the Windows 10 operating system (no separate data partition here).
There's also a reserved space (less than 0.5 GB) at the beginning of disk space. Since this is a laptop with an OEM system I assume this is some kind of recovery partition.

My goal is to encrypt this disk securely without exposing any data through temp files or by other means.
And of course, I need a way to choose which Windows OS I want to boot.
I know that full disk encryption is the most secure option but if I am properly informed it's not possible in my situation.

Second question:
I wonder if it would be possible to access an encrypted Windows 7 D: (data) drive from Windows 10?
Sometimes I do this but if it can't be done or would be insecure I can live without it.

Comment: This question already exists: https://superuser.com/q/1807508/432690

Comment: @niref, Do not duplicate your question -- delete one.